# How to exclude hidden folder/files from getting copied using Copy-Item in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have this below code which is used to copy DBUpgrade folder to another location, but it copies the hidden folder present inside it as well.

```
$Demo="F:\source\DBUpgrade"

$new="F:\Test" 

Copy-Item $demo $new -Recurse -Force
```

Is there any command by which I can exclude the hidden folder and one more thing the name of the hidden folder is `$tf` because of which i am not able to use remove-item command to remove the folder itself as another option.

Comment: Remove `-Force`.

Comment: No, It still copies the hidden folder..

Comment: Quote with single quotes like `Remove-Item '$tf'` to stop the `$tf` part being treated as a variable, or escape the dollar with a backtick.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, Thanks it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a

`$list = get-childitem $demo $new -recurse -attributes !H | select fullname`

And than a foreach loop

`foreach ($file in $list){
Copy commands go here
}`

Mind you copy commands will require some finesse to get it in the right folder and may not be worth the hassle
You'll have to trim the path out and do checks if it's $demo or $new to get it to the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

Get-Childitem by default doesn't show hidden items

[image]